# Android: Scrollable and zoomable container

Tags: android, scroll

I'm looking for a way to display views (like buttons, checkboxes, images etc) in a container, which might be bigger than the actual screen size.

A ScrollView within a HorizontalScrollView is no option, since you're only able to scroll one direction at once, not diagonal.

I have yet to find a simple solution to this problem. A zoom function would be nice to have, but that's not as important as the ability to scroll diagonal.

Are there any components out there able to do things like these? Doesn't even have to be for free.

Comment: "Are there any components out there able to do things like these?" No! Been doing this for long time and only two things I saw are scrollable in any direction: maps or games. Maps are closed source APIs that usually just renders tiles of images (not Views) and games uses Game engines and render all in OpenGL. Exception is Google Maps which uses OpenGL to render in a similar fashion as games do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found a ScrollView which works surpringsly well in terms of scrolling diagonal. (At least on first sight) [link](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/CustomScrollViews/blob/master/library/src/com/doomonafireball/customscrollviews/widget/TwoDScrollView.java). Still no zooming, but better than nothing...

Comment: would share the link ?

Comment: I did, have a look at my comment again :)

Comment: ops... my bad! I'll check it out.